# Silverlight: How to work with layouts relative to screen size?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm working with Silverlight 4. I have a control that is wide enough that it goes off the screen. If I expand the window enough, I can see it, but I'd rather the control shrink so that it's visible in a smaller window. How can I specify this?

Comment: It would help if you included the problem xaml to allow for more concrete comment

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the control into a ViewBox.

Comment: this, or use the grid rows/columns and have it grow with the real-estate it has to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it might be helpful to look at the Silverlight Toolkit Samples.  The LayoutTransformer example does some resizing like you describe.

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html#/Navigation/Page2.xaml